# Aligning group of images in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

```
<img src="abroad.jpg" alt="country" width="495" height="262.5">

<img src="bubbles.jpg" alt="colourful" width="495" height="262.5">

<img src="butterflies.jpg" alt="nature" width="495" height="262.5">
```

For this code, how do I align all of the images so that they are in the center and not to the left of the page?

Comment: `margin:0px auto` .. or `display:inline-block`, `text-align:center` http://jsfiddle.net/eLwzt/

Comment: @JoshC An image is inline-block by default, isn't it?

Comment: @GolezTrol Yep - you're right. Just thought I would say that as the defaults might have been changed. For all I know, they are `block`.. **EDIT** Looking at the element right now, and it actually says that the defaults are `inline` rather than `inline-block` still has the same effect though.

Comment: do you want them center aligned and on top of each other, or you want the images side by side center aligned in the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dT66/